# PowerShell script doesnt return data the first run through

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have created a PowerShell script to find the computer name from the values in the description. We put the users name in the description and computer name is an asset tag number. If you continue and put the name in a second time it works. If you look for another user you have to do it twice also.

Here is my script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

do {
    $a = Read-Host "Enter first or last name of user"
    $b = "*$a*"

    # Validates if the command returns data
    $searcher = $(try {
        Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -like $b} -Properties
Name,Description | Select Name,Description
    } catch {
        $null
    })

    if ($searcher -ne $null) {
        Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -like $b } -Properties Name,Description |
            Select Name,Description
    } else {
        Write-Host Could not find: $a -ForegroundColor "yellow"
    }

    # If running in the console, wait for input before closing.
    if ($Host.Name -eq "ConsoleHost") {
        Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null
    }
    $again = Read-Host 'Would you like to search again? (Y/N)'
} until ($again -eq 'No' -or $again -eq 'n')
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your script other than the statement inside the `try..catch` being wrapped incorrectly. Does the statement look like that in your actual code, or did you just mistype it in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example using your script with a few changes.

The big change that allowed it to work was piping to `Out-Host` from using `Get-ADComputer`

```
# installs AD module 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Do {
    $a = Read-Host "Enter first or last name of user"
    $b = "*$a*"

    try {
        Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -like $b} -Properties Name, Description -ErrorVariable MyError | 
            Select-Object Name,Description | 
            Out-Host

        if ($MyError){
            write-host Could not find: $a -foregroundcolor Yellow
        }
    } 
    catch {
        write-host Could not find: $a -foregroundcolor Red
    }
    $again = Read-host 'Would you like to search again? (Y/N)'
} 
Until (
    $again -eq 'No' -or $again -eq 'n'
)
```